# R function to pull out pairwise combinations of well values from incomplete dataframe?

Tags: r

I am looking to create a data frame that extracts cell value pairs from another dataframe.

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
C1 = c("A","B","C","A","A","B","A")
C2 = c("","","","B","C","C","B")
C3 = c("","","","","","","C")
df <- cbind(C1, C2, C3) 
row.names(df) <-  c("A", "B", "C", "AB", "AC", "BC", "ABC")
colnames(df) <- c("First_Item", "Second_Item","Third_Item")
```

Now I want to take each cell item to create a dataframe like this:

```
C1_2 = c("","","","A:B","A:C","B:C","A:B")
C2_2 = c("","","","","","","B:C")
df_2 <- cbind(C1_2, C2_2) 
row.names(df_2) <-  c("A", "B", "C", "AB", "AC", "BC", "ABC")
colnames(df_2) <- c("Interaction_01", "Interaction_02")
```

any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 1):

This would work for any number of columns -

```
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- x[x!='']
  if(length(y) > 1) 
    c(paste(head(y, -1), tail(y, -1), sep = ':'), rep('', length(x) - length(y)))
  else rep('', length(x) - 1)
})))

#     X1  X2
#A          
#B          
#C          
#AB  A:B    
#AC  A:C    
#BC  B:C    
#ABC A:B B:C
```

---

To get all the combinations use `combn` -

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- x[x!='']
  if(length(y) > 1) 
    combn(y, 2, paste0, collapse = ':')
  else ''
}) -> res
n <- max(lengths(res))
t(sapply(res, function(x) c(x, rep('', n - length(x)))))

#  [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
#A   ""    ""    ""   
#B   ""    ""    ""   
#C   ""    ""    ""   
#AB  "A:B" ""    ""   
#AC  "A:C" ""    ""   
#BC  "B:C" ""    ""   
#ABC "A:B" "A:C" "B:C"
```

Comment: thanks, this worked well for sliding along the interactions but I just realized I also need other interactions such as between A and C in the last row...

Comment: @AlisonR. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 3 columns, this should do the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)
C1 = c("A","B","C","A","A","B","A")
C2 = c("","","","B","C","C","B")
C3 = c("","","","","","","C")
df <- cbind(C1, C2, C3) 
row.names(df) <-  c("A", "B", "C", "AB", "AC", "BC", "ABC")
colnames(df) <- c("First_Item", "Second_Item","Third_Item")

result <- df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    pre_interaction_1 = paste(First_Item, Second_Item, sep = ":"),
    pre_interaction_2 = paste(First_Item, Third_Item, sep = ":"),
    interaction_1 = case_when(
      str_count(pre_interaction_1) == 2 ~ "",
      TRUE ~ pre_interaction_1
    ),
    interaction_2 = case_when(
      str_count(pre_interaction_2) == 2 ~ "",
      TRUE ~ pre_interaction_2
    )
  ) %>%
  select(
    interaction_1,
    interaction_2
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `""` with `NA` you could do this in a quite concise way.

```
df[df == ''] <- NA
r <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) combn(x, 2, function(y) paste(y, collapse=':'))))
r[grep('NA', r)] <- ''
r
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
# A   ""    ""    ""   
# B   ""    ""    ""   
# C   ""    ""    ""   
# AB  "A:B" ""    ""   
# AC  "A:C" ""    ""   
# BC  "B:C" ""    ""   
# ABC "A:B" "A:C" "B:C"
```

`paste()` coerces `NA` to `"NA"`, which we exploit here using `grep()` which selects those cells that contain it.